# How to use computed properties to form date with slash or dash?

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties

In edit form, there are two dropdown select to allow user to choose the `data separator` and `date format`.

I've declared data for both date separator and date format in `route.js`.

```
  dataDateFormat = {
    dateSeparator:"-",
    dateFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD"
  };
```

Here is the code for `date separator` options.

```
{{#paper-select options=this.dateSeparator
  selected=model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator
  onchange=(action (mut model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator)) as |dateSep| }}
    {{dateSep}}
  {{/paper-select}}
```

Here is the code for `date format` options.

```
{{#paper-select options=this.fullDate
  selected=model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat
  onchange=(action (mut model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat)) as |date| }}
    {{date}}
{{/paper-select}}
```

In `controller.js`, I've declared a computed property `fullDate`, which I want to return the date format with the date separator that the user choose. For example, when the user choose `-` as the date separator, the date format option will be change based on the date separator, `YYYY-MM-DD, DD-MM-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY`. So how can I do this using computed properties?

```
@computed('model.dataDateFormat')
  get fullDate() {
    return `${this.model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator} ${this.model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat}`;
  }

init() {
  dateSeparator: [
    "-","/"
  ],
 dateFormat:[
    "YYYY MM DD",
    "DD MM YYYY",
    "MM DD YYYY"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, there must be a misstake. your `init` is invalid syntax.

Next I think the important step here is that you probably should keep the format independent of the separator. And just combine both for formatting. So maybe something like `{ first: 'DD', middle: 'MM', last: 'YYYY' }`. Then you would not need a computed at all.

It could look like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
  dateSeparators = Object.freeze([
    "-",
    "/",
  ]);
  dateFormats = Object.freeze([
    { first: 'YYYY', middle: 'MM', last: 'DD' },
    { first: 'DD', middle: 'MM', last: 'YYYY' },
    { first: 'MM', middle: 'DD', last: 'YYYY' },
  ]);
}
```

Not you can just combine it in the template:

```
{{#paper-select options=this.dateFormats
  selected=model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat
  onchange=(action (mut model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat)) as |format| }}
    {{format.first}}{{model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator}}{{format.middle}}{{model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator}}{{model.last}}
{{/paper-select}}
```

Now the reason here a computed property on this level will not work is because you would need it *inside* the `{{#paper-select`, and there *multiple times*.

However if you want you could write a component. Then you could have this controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
  dateSeparators = Object.freeze([
    "-",
    "/",
  ]);
  dateFormats = Object.freeze([
    ['YYYY', 'MM', 'DD'],
    ['DD', 'MM', 'YYYY'],
    ['MM', 'DD', 'YYYY'],
  ]);
}
```

now there is no easy way to access the 3 elements of that array in hbs (a custom helper could sove this, but we're looking into the component solution now),

So you could do this:

```
{{#paper-select options=this.dateFormats
  selected=model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat
  onchange=(action (mut model.dataDateFormat.dateFormat)) as |format| }}
    <DateFormat
      @format={{format}}
      @seperator={{this.model.dataDateFormat.dateSeparator}}
    />
{{/paper-select}}
```

No inside the `DateFormat` component you can have the `computed`:

```
class DateFormatComponent extends Component { // this is a classic component, not a glimmer component
  @computed('format', 'seperator') formatWithSeperator() {
    return this.format.join(this.seperator);
  }
}
```

And then the template can just be `{{formatWithSeperator}}`

---

A short notice: Note that a changed the options from singular `dateFormat` to plural `dateFormats`. Its *always* a good idea to use plural for arrays to make it clearer.